# How to change color of the number based on the value of the number. (Open to using any of the tags)

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, css

How do I change color of the number (text-color) based on the value of the number.
So basically I have a database where I store data in like temperature, humidity, pressure, ammoniac values. I fetch this data and show it on an overview / table on my website. It will show the latest entry in the database.
Now if the temperature has a very low/cold value like 5 degrees celsius or somewhere in the minus the number will be red. If the temperature value is between 19-26 degrees celsius it will be green. If its high temperature like 31 degrees celsius it will be red. Also orange color amidst.

How can I create/realize this? Through jquery or javascript or even css. Could you guys help me? Here is my code for everything.

EDITED
So I tried both Adams code and devpros code. Both seem to work with the good/green temperature, so I decided to mix both parts and came up with this code with orange and red. But Orange and red don't seem to work. Could you guys help me?

```
     <?php
                                require_once "dbconnect.php";
                                echo '<table class="table is-bordered is-striped is-narrow is-hoverable is-fullwidth">
                                <tr>
                                <th>Date</th>
                                <th>Temperatuur</th>

                                <th>Humidity</th>
                                <th>Dust</th>
                                <th>CO2</th>
                                <th>Ammoniac</th>
                                <th>Pressure</th>
                                </tr>';

                                $result = $conn->prepare("SELECT * FROM `Climate_Data` ORDER BY `ID` DESC LIMIT 1");
                                    $result->execute();



                                      //Set a default class, just in case no temps match
  $scoreClass = 'reg-temp-class';

  for($i=0; $row = $result->fetch(); $i++){


      //Temp is between 19 and 26 (can be equal to 19 or 26 as well)
      if ($row['temperature'] >= 16 && $row['temperature'] <= 27){
          $scoreClass = 'green';
      }
      elseif ($row['temperature'] <= 15 && $row['temperature'] >= 27){
          $scoreClass = 'orange';
      }
      elseif ($row['temperature'] <= 5 && $row['temperature'] >= 31){
          $scoreClass = 'red';
      }
      echo "<tr>";
      echo "<td>" . $row['Date'] . "</td>";
      echo "<td class='".$scoreClass."'>" . $row['temperature'] . "</td>";
      echo "<td>" . $row['Humidity'] . "</td>";
      echo "<td>" . $row['dust'] . "</td>";
      echo "<td>" . $row['co2'] . "</td>";
      echo "<td>" . $row['ammoniac'] . "</td>";
      echo "<td>" . $row['pressure'] . "</td>";
      echo "</tr>";

  }

                                echo "</table>";
       ?>

     <style>
   .green {
  color: green;
     }
    .orange {
    color: orange;
    }
    .red {
      color: red;
    }
  </style>
```

I am up for anything jquery etc. I just need help with this. I am using the bulma framework. But if you all know of any  other or better way of presenting this instead of a long table it would be appreciated. I just want something nice looking maybe even a list. Thanks in advance!

Comment: `id='score'` inside for loop will create issue, u cant defined ID twice, use unique ID or class

Comment: Just assign a class to the temperature (using some PHP IF logic for ranges), and then use CSS to style the element with the class*

Comment: @Adam "style the class" I think you mean style the *element* *with a class*

Comment: one more suggestion, u can use php for this activity with inline css,

Comment: did u tried these?

Comment: Yeah I tried both, I think the one from Adam does the trick. But whenever I add the part for orange and red then it doesn't work. What could I do, I updated the code above, could you please take a look. @everyone

Comment: What r the ranges?

Comment: @devpro I updated the code. Could you check it? Ranges if ($row['temperature'] >= 16 && $row['temperature'] <= 27){
          $scoreClass = 'green';
      }
      elseif ($row['temperature'] <= 15 && $row['temperature'] >= 27){
          $scoreClass = 'orange';
      }
      elseif ($row['temperature'] <= 5 && $row['temperature'] >= 31){
          $scoreClass = 'red';
      }

Comment: I know that, but its because it has to do with being too hot and too cold. Thats why its orange and after red. Otherwise I will have to make a new scoreclass 1 for too cold and 1  for too hot. How can I do this?

Comment: is it working? ??

Comment: i have updated my answer. please check

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Or you can use simple `PHP` script and inline `CSS` to change color according to your conditions:

**Example (use inside your loop):**

```
<?php
$color = '';
if($row['temperature'] >= 40){
    $color = 'orange';
}
elseif($row['temperature'] >= 60){
    $color = 'green';
}
else{
    $color = 'red'; 
}
echo "<td style='color:".$color."'>" . $row['temperature'] . "</td>";
?>
```

**Important:** One more thing, as i mentioned in my comments, in your example `id='score'` will create issue, because you can only use ID at once, not twice.

**Edit:**

According to your comment, your conditions will be implemented as like:

```
<?php
$color = '';
if($row['temperature'] <= 5){ // 5,4,3,2,1,0,-1 .....
    $color = 'red';
}
elseif($row['temperature'] <= 15){ // 6 to 15
    $color = 'orange';
}
elseif($row['temperature'] <= 27){ // 16 to 27
    $color = 'green';
}
elseif($row['temperature'] < 31){ // 27 to 30
    $color = 'orange';
}
else{
    $color = 'red';  // >= 31
}
?>
```

Comment: Hey thanks a lot for helping me. I tried your code, it works for the most part. But I added some layers to it. Because now it only works for the "green" temperature in between that, it will show the temperature in green. But now if I add the orange temperature (IF temp lower than 15 show in orange, or if temp higher than 27 show in orange) it doesn't work. Same goes for red (If temp lower than 5 red, if temp higher than 31 show red). I need help. I updated the code above so you could look at it. Its need to be more specific.

Comment: @M.Tijms: check **Edit**

Answer (score 1):

You could use CSS, or JS, I'm going to do it in PHP with some simple logic (others may have a better answer). The IF statement allows you to decide what the temperature range is, set a 'class' for use in your TD's element a little later.

Note the && operator so that we ensure the temperature must be between X and X numbers.

```
//Set a default class, just in case no temps match
$scoreClass = 'reg-temp-class';

for($i=0; $row = $result->fetch(); $i++){

    //Temp is between 19 and 26 (can be equal to 19 or 26 as well)
    if ($row['temperature'] >= 19 && $row['temperature'] <= 26){
        $scoreClass = 'cold';
    }

    echo "<tr>";
    echo "<td>" . $row['Date'] . "</td>";
    echo "<td class='".$scoreClass."'>" . $row['temperature'] . "</td>";
    echo "<td>" . $row['Humidity'] . "</td>";
    echo "<td>" . $row['dust'] . "</td>";
    echo "<td>" . $row['co2'] . "</td>";
    echo "<td>" . $row['ammoniac'] . "</td>";
    echo "<td>" . $row['pressure'] . "</td>";
    echo "</tr>";

}
```

Then you could use some CSS:

```
<style>
.cold {
    color: #ff0000;
}
</style>
```

Edit: Adding in extra logic so that you can handle multiple different temperatures. This would replace the IF statement at the beginning of your foreach above. I've modified your code (from your comment).

- If Temp is = to or higher than 16 AND = or lower than 27, show green.
- If Temp is lower than 15 AND higher than 27, show orange.
- If Temp is lower than 5 AND higher than 31, show red

  ```
  if ($row['temperature'] >= 16 && $row['temperature'] <= 27){ 
      $scoreClass = 'green'; 
  } elseif ($row['temperature'] < 15 && $row['temperature'] > 27){
      $scoreClass = 'orange'; 
  } elseif ($row['temperature'] < 5 && $row['temperature'] > 31){ 
      $scoreClass = 'red'; 
  }
  ```

Comment: Hey thanks a lot for helping me. I tried your code, it works for the most part. But I added some layers to it. Because now it only works for the "green" temperature in between that, it will show the temperature in green. But now if I add the orange temperature (IF temp lower than 15 show in orange, or if temp higher than 27 show in orange) it doesn't work. Same goes for red (If temp lower than 5 red, if temp higher than 31 show red). I need help. I updated the code above so you could look at it. Thanks Adam

Comment: The logic doesn't make sense I feel. Typically, you'd use ranges that are like 1-10, 11-15, 16-20 (for example). In your scenario, a temp could be lower than 15, but higher than 27 and be 'orange'?

Comment: I know that, but its because it has to do with being too hot and too cold. Thats why its orange and after red. Otherwise I will have to make a new scoreclass 1 for too cold and 1  for too hot. How can I do this?

Comment: I've made an edit which *should* work, let me know if that gets you closer to what you're looking for.

Comment: The remade code still doesn't work. Temperature = 12.008 shows in black. Does it matter if the temperature comes at in a float?

Comment: I'm not entirely sure, but I'd imagine so. You could cast it to a round number if possible? `ceil()` will round it up, `floor()` will round it down.

Comment: How do I do this?